# Displaying ADDBTimeStamp with visual c++ 6.0

Tags: visual-c++, ado, foxpro

I'm using the ADO (msado15.dll) to access visual foxpro dbf tables from a visual c++ 6.0 console application and displaying the info to the screen. I can access all the data types in the table and printf them to the screen except the addbtimestamp type. How do I printf an adddbtimestamp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution. I did some MFC/Database tutorials and VC uses the COleDateTime to convert the database dateTime field.

```
// CREATE COleDateTime VAR m_TDATE = COleDateTime::GetCurrentTime(); m_TDATE = m_pSet->m_tableDateTime;
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like that may be a column created by the ADO driver. VFP has a DateTime and Date column types, but not the type that you mention. It's probably a column added by the driver.

Comment: Thanks for the commanent Jerry, Yes it is an ADO type of 8 Bytes in yyyymmddhhmmss format but I'm trying to get the value to display using printf to no avail. I've tried %I64 %llu and all the types I could google up but have had no luck displaying the timestamp.

Comment: This sounds more like a ADO question, not a Foxpro issue. My guess is that this is a DateTime type of column. But perhaps this article will help: http://www.w3schools.com/ado/ado_datatypes.asp

Comment: Hi again Jerry, yea it's an ADO and c question for sure. I included foxpro in there as background and to help other foxpro coders find this in case they had the same trouble. I understand the datatype and found it on this page http://webcoder.info/reference/MSSQLDataTypes.html too. What I don't understand is how to printf the value to the screen using c. I think it may need converting first but like I said i'm not very versed in c.

Comment: Assuming that the column is a DateTime type, try converting it to string: var value = new DateTime(2012, 1, 1).ToString()  or var value = adddbtimestamp.ToString(). Be sure to make as answer if you find this helpful.

Comment: I've found a solution. I did some MFC/Database tutorials and VC uses the COleDateTime to convert the database dateTime field.

// CREATE COleDateTime VAR 
m_TDATE = COleDateTime::GetCurrentTime();
m_TDATE = m_pSet->m_tableDateTime;